# Windows server 2012 on laptop

Tags: laptop, windows-server-2012

There is situation where I can take 1 `Microsoft Windows Server 2012 Standard 64-bit` license for free. **Is it worth installing it on laptop? Any pros\cons?**

I'm using laptop for software development, movies, Internet.

Laptop specs: Intel Core i7 - 3612QM CPU, 16GB RAM, 1TB Hard Drive, 2GB ATI Radeon Video card. I am currently using Windows 7 professional.

Comment: Back in the Windows XP and Vista days, there was a lot of benefit to be gained from installing a server edition of Windows and then setting up the Server to also have some client OS features,  instead of, well, XP or Vista. That benefit is greatly reduced, as more recent client versions of Windows suck less, and recent server editions of Windows are more effective at hiding away the client features and tuning.

Comment: You WILL run into compatability problems.  Windows Server 2012 IS NOT Windows 8.

Answer (score 3):

Quite honestly, it would take a lot of work to get the Windows 7 functionality on and the Server functionality off. Stick with Windows 7, as you have nothing in this instance to gain otherwise